# Why visited picture doesn't get radius

Tags: html, css

Please, can you tell me why when I visit one of the two links in the code, the picture does not get radius? And what can I do to get that done?
**Notice the `a:visited div.container div.title` works fine**

```
<html>
<head><title>Some title</title>
<style>
.container
{
    width : 100;
    height : 100;
}

.title
{
    position : absolute;
}

a:visited.container img.pic
{
    border-radius:50%;
}

a:visited div.container div.title
{
    color : red;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<a href="#link01">
    <div class="container">
        <img class="pic" src="leb.jpg">
        <div class="title">Title 01
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#link02">
    <div class="container">
        <img class="pic" src="leb.jpg">
        <div class="title">Title 02
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From w3schools.com

> Definition and Usage
>   The :visited selector is used to select visited links.
>
> Tip: Use the :link selector to style links to unvisited pages, the
>   :hover selector to style links when you mouse over them, and the
>   :active selector to style links when you click on them.
>
> Browsers limits the styles that can be set for a:visited links, due to
>   security issues.
>
> Allowed styles are:
>
> color background-color border-color (and border-color for separate
>   sides) outline color column-rule-color the color parts of fill and
>   stroke All other styles are inherited from a:link.

You can use javascript for this purpose but not $("a:visited") since they don't support it anymore.

Solution with click event

```
a.visited .pic {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

then import jQuery and add these lines between  tags. This will add "visited" class on every clicked link

```
 $("a").on('click' , function() {
  $(this).addClass("visited");
})
```

Be aware after page reloads classes will be lost

Comment: Thanks for the reply Still cant get it done,Can you implement some code :)

Comment: I still did not get what I want ,because I want to use only css no javascript no jQuery ,If you have anything new please mention it ,Thanks for your time

Comment: No , sorry , you can't do this only with css as i said it before, there is browser restrictions now. You can check it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the declaration:

Instead of

```
a:visited.container img.pic
```

use

```
a.container:visited img.pic
```

I just saw another issue: None of your  tags have the class .container set. I guess you mean something like that:

```
a:visited div.container img.pic
```

Also, the first declaration looks strange:

```
.container
{
    width : 100;
    height : 100;
}
```

You did not put any unit there (but it is necessary).

I recommend to change it to

```
.container
{
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
}
```

Comment: Saw another issue, changed my answer

Comment: Wow fast replies I think my friend 'a:visited.container img.pic' same as 'a:visited .container img.pic' either ways still does not work